# NoMethodError in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've encountered the following error while trying to create a blogging application. Any ideas why?

---

```
NoMethodError in Articles#show

Showing app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `title' for []:Array
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <h2><%= @article.title %></h2>
2:  
3: <% if @article.category %>
4:   <p class="category">
```

---

From my limited understanding it's trying to tell me that there is no 'title' field in my 'article' database table, however as you can see from the desc below there is cleary a 'title' field!

```
mysql> desc articles;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| synopsis     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| body         | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| published    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| published_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Help?!

Bernard

Ps. hope the formatting of the table above holds up... doesn't seem to look very good in the preview!

---

Controller code for relevant call as follows.

```
def show
if is_logged_in? && @logged_in_user.has_role?('Editor')
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
else
    @article = Article.find_all_by_published(params[:id], true)
end
respond_to do |wants|
    wants.html
    wants.xml { render :xml => @article.to_xml }
end
end
```

Comment: The error suggests that you have received an entire array where you think you have one item from the array. That is, an individual article has a title, but not the array holding all the article objects. (I don't work with Rails, but as I recall there's some magic to the way it handles singulars and plurals. That recollection is pretty vague, so feel free to ignore it.)

Comment: In such case consider to debug a bit yourself before sending to a forum: e.g. output @article.class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're trying to access the title element directly from the array. You'll need to iterate through each of the objects before you can access the properties.

```
for @article in @articles do |a|
   <h2><%= a.title %></h2>...
end
```

Just make sure to have in your controller...

```
@articles = Article.find(:all, :conditions => '...')
```

**Update**:

This part of your code returns a collection.

```
@article = Article.find_all_by_published(params[:id], true)
```

Comment: Hmm... dunno. In my controller I search for a particular ID in the Articles array, and populate @articles with that result? 
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
Thought this would have meant that @article would be an element and not an array?

Comment: Yeah it does. I was only speculating.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're assigning an empty array to `@article` in your controller. It should instead be an instance of `Article` (if that's your model name). Can you paste your controller code?

Comment: Relevent controller code is as follows: -
  def show
   if is_logged_in? && @logged_in_user.has_role?('Editor')
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   else
    @article = Article.find_all_by_published(params[:id], true)
   end
   respond_to do |wants|
    wants.html
    wants.xml { render :xml => @article.to_xml }
   end
  end

Alexey would love a pointer on how to debug Rails code, at the moment I'm just going off log files and web-output! Worry definitely a Rails (and programming) newb...